# python: subprocess gives me different results while using sudo

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, sudo

I'm using python to do some tests and I get a very weird issue as below:

First I have a simple bash script named `1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'NOTHING'
```

Then I make such a python script named `test.py` in the same directory as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import os

os.environ['PS4'] = "aaa "
res=subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-x', '1.sh'], stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
print res.stderr.readlines()
```

To my surprise, when I execute `./test.py`, I get the result:

> NOTHING
>   ['aaa echo NOTHING\n']

and when I execute `sudo ./test.py`, I get:

> NOTHING
>   ['+ echo NOTHING\n']

What I need is `aaa` whereas it becomes a `+` now just because of `sudo`.

Why?

The version of my python: 2.7.12
The system: ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there has been a bug in bash, allowing arbitrary code injection through inherited PS4 variable in root shell. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1379630

The bug has been fixed, and it appears PS4 is completely ignored if bash is run as root. You can test this:

```
sudo bash
export PS4="xyzzy "
bash -x 1.sh
```

and notice you still get +. No matter what you set in PS4, it seems to be never displayed if your uid is zero. This of course is not a solution, but if this is true, what you want to do cannot be done with PS4.

As a workaround I suggest reading `res.stderr` line by line and running a regexp based substitution replacing `^+` with your chosen prompt.